# Why does IntelliJ start my Kotlin Gradle program despite of compilation errors

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a standard JVM Kotlin project set up with IntelliJ IDEA. In the following image you can see my run configuration.
[image: IntelliJ Run Debug configuration screenshot]

Currently I am having compile errors (as by `Build Project` Ctrl + F9)
[image: Proof of compile error]

However, if I execute the run configuration the program is executed. Definitly not the current version as I have compile errors.

**Actual behavior:** Run config executes program despite having compile errors and project build fails

**Expected behavior:** Run configuration fails on build project and does not start an older version of my program

IntelliJ version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.7141.44, built on May 7, 2019
JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.56 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: If the issue persists with the current IDE version and the latest Kotlin plug-in, please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.